# Trying to upload an image file from resources dir with selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, jenkins, resources

for an absolute file path, I use something like the following:

`getWebDriver().findElement(By.id("LogoInput")).sendKeys(/Users/username/pics/logo.jpg);`

This runs fine on my local machine but I need it to run on Jenkins.

I am having a hard time trying to use the resources dir in IntelliJ.

I need a path (String) to the resources dir in my project folder so that it can be passed in to the `sendKeys()` method so that Jenkins would understand it when it runs on its slave.

Comment: You may use a relativa path. And you can say your IDE to deploy the content of the resources file on the classes folder of your app. Un eclipse this option is named deployment assembly.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using java you should use  System.getProperty("user.dir") for top directory of your project and this will complete absolute path

```
getWebDriver().findElement(By.id("LogoInput")).sendKeys(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Users/username/pics/logo.jpg");
```